# factoring out a singularity of a 2nd order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, singularity

I am looking at a 2nd order ODE:

\begin{equation}
   \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + p(x)\frac{du}{dx} + q(x) u = 0 .
\end{equation}

that has five regular singular points: say at $0$, $1$, $a$, $b$, and $\infty$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. I suspect I can ``factor out'' one singularity of the equation (as is done for example for another equation [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9805064)), and thus transform this equation into a Heun equation. Is there a general way/theory/procedure to determine when one can factor out a singularity for a given ode? I'd greatly appreciate a simple demonstration, example, or references to the literature on this subject.